# After Deleting .thumbdata file all images in sd card are corrupted

Tags: sd-card, photos, images, gallery, thumbnails

I am suffering from media corruption on my SD Card, I have deleted .thumbdata file on my android phone (Samsung J7 Prime) to freeup space on sd card but after deletion all files are corrupted and showing error while opening.

is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have try to open the images on a PC to check if they are really corrupted? Try to delete the data of Media Storage, restart the phone.

Comment: **How** did you delete it?